# Wordpress landing page

Tags: wordpress

I have a HTML file with some CSS and few images. I can upload it on request.

I need to make that my landing page, so when a user joins my website he would be redirected to that page. I've tried to find a plugin I could use but every plugin has its own layouts and templates and I can't use my HTML in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your Homepage, just find in your "templates" folder the "home template" of your theme and change this html page by yours (don't forget to add your css).

Answer (score 0):

Just save the html in your theme directory with the name `home.php`.

Checkout the WordPress Template Hierarchy (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to learn more about how templates are loaded within themes. It's vital information if you're building your own Wordpress theme(s).

Comment: I'm running a business so I'm not actually doing a lot of web related business. Thing is, that needs to be landing page with a button that will lead to homepage. Do I have to replace everything now?